# HOW DO I TRANSFER MY VOX COIN FROM A CUSTOM ADDRESS WITH DECIMAL 6 TO A ADDRESS WITH DECIMAL 18

Tags: transactions, contract-design, tokens, smart-contract-wallets

I have Vox coin but on a contract address and with decimal 6 and on Smart Chain Network.. I transferred my coin to another Vox coin wallet with Decimal 18 but show as 0.00, if I should add custom token address and decimal 6, it shows the initial value. Please how do I transfer my coin in a contract wallet with decimal 6 to a contract wallet with decimal 18 and initial value sent shows instead of 0.00

Comment: Can you give more detail of what you are trying to achieve. A token has a fixed decimals value and it will not change.

Comment: On Trust Wallet I added a custom token with Decimal 6, I want to transfer my coins to another wallet address with Decimal 18, but shows 0.00 on the wallet with Decimal 18..what I want to archive it to transfer my coins from the custom token wallet with Decimal 6 to decimal 18 and initial transaction amount shows completely so I can trade

Comment: The number of decimals is used for presentation. It is better if you configure both wallets to use the decimals from the token contract. You can make it works but you have to multiply or divide by 10^(18 - 6) = 10^12 when transferring.

Comment: Please How do I move my token from Smartchain Network to Binance or Blockchain Network?